# Business Logics of projects under MVVM in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, business-logic

I am developing an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern. If I have Student as a data model, for example, where could I add the business logic like adding new Students, deleting Students and updating Student info, calculating marks and so on?

Does all the business logics come under the **model** or the **viewmodel**?

If it is in the model how can we do that? Any example code please? I need full code for an example!

Comment: Note that this question does not state the architecture of the full solution. MVVM is just a pattern for the Client application. If the client connects to services, those services will need to implement the business rules and logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Business logic should be part of of your model, as all of that code should be reusable across different technology platforms.  For example, you may want to reuse your models across a web site in ASP.NET MVC, and a desktop application in WPF, so it wouldn't make sense to have business logic in your view models.

View models should contain presentation logic which is specific to that particular application instance.

As for example code, this will be specific to the domain that you are modelling, so you would have to ask a more specific question about what you are trying to model.

Comment: Thanks man, Actually i am developing a product Information system for that can i get code? i mean example code

Comment: That isn't really possible without expert domain knowledge in the domain you are working in.  I would start creating your models, and when you come to a specific problem, post another question here.

Comment: Well our models are actually CSLA objects (http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/), but you can just use POCO classes - for example you may have a Student class with properties for Forename, Surname, DateOfBirth etc, and maybe a StudentList which is a List<Student> and provides your aggregate methods.

Comment: Also, have a look at this great article on MVVM - http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) documentation on this subject: [Chapter 5: Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx).

Even if you don't plan to use PRISM, the article is very well written and details the pattern in Microsoft's technology terms.

Answer (score 1):

I would trust very little of what Microsoft has to say on Patterns as their articles are often dated, or modified to support their own proprietary frameworks or products. Also I've found MS thoughts/approaches contradictory within their different teams and also within the generally accepted approach in software.

Not all of it is good and not all of it is bad basically.

To answer your question. I'd use a Service for Business Logic. I'd instantiate a reference to it in the ViewModel and I would not put any logic in either the ViewModel or the Model that did not have anything to do with their role. ie Presentation logic is okay dependingon what it is, it might be best placed in the ViewModel as it is highly tied to the View in question. Same goes for the model.

Keeping in mind these roles you will have a scaleable and testable application.